# SELECT subquery returns NULL values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to turn this query with INNER JOIN into a nested query.

```
SELECT starttime, name
FROM cd.facilities
INNER JOIN cd.bookings
USING (facid)
WHERE name LIKE 'Tennis Court%'
AND DATE(starttime) = '2012-09-21'
ORDER BY starttime ASC;
```

I'm getting somewhere with what I've tried, but apart from the valid values in 'name'
I also get a lot of null values. What am I missing? Is this piece of code salvageable?

```
SELECT starttime, 
(SELECT name FROM cd.facilities
 WHERE name LIKE 'Tennis Court%'
 AND cd.bookings.facid = cd.facilities.facid) AS name
FROM cd.bookings
WHERE DATE(starttime) = '2012-09-21'
ORDER BY starttime ASC;
```

Comment: Why are you _trying to turn this query with INNER JOIN into a nested query_? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)  [mcve].

Comment: A subquery in the SELECT clause is not allowed to return more than one row. Your query doesn't look 100% safe. That's an indication that something is a bit strange here.

Comment: I'm practicing subqueries and I wanted to accomplish turning an inner join into one by following another example (from a course). Though in that example, they'd used COUNT, so I can see why it made sense to do this. Is it safe to conclude that if a SELECT subquery would return multiple rows I should stick to JOINs?

Comment: You can have a subquery in the FROM clause that returns several rows, which you JOIN. (Such subquery in the FROM clause us called _derived table_.) You can also do IN or EXISTS a subquery that returns several rows.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your answer. As I understand so far, using WHERE IN and WHERE EXISTS I can't actually select columns from another table, but only use them as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

The inner join returns only rows for where there is a match for facid.  The subquery returns null (in name) for where there is no match.   If you want to move forward with this, you can probably just eliminate the rows with nulls in name like this for instance:

```
select * from (SELECT starttime, 
(SELECT name FROM cd.facilities
 WHERE name LIKE 'Tennis Court%'
 AND cd.bookings.facid = cd.facilities.facid) AS name
FROM cd.bookings
WHERE DATE(starttime) = '2012-09-21'
ORDER BY starttime ASC) d where name is not null;
```

Best regards,Bjarni

Comment: Moving the ORDER BY into a subquery means the final result can come in any order.

Comment: This is by no means a well thought out query.  Just trying to answer the question on why the subquery wasn't working as the inner join.